# MySQL – RAM-size sufficient?

Tags: mysql, ram

I'm relatively new to MySQL databases. I'm currently designing a small web application which main feature will be a fulltext search and, despite reading the docs, am still curious about the amount of RAM size my hoster (mediatemple) provides and if it will be sufficient enough for my needs or if I should upgrade (64MB, 128MB & 512MB RAM possible).

```
*** MySQL database specs***

* RAM: 64MB
* Max storage size: 4GB
* Server: Percona Server
* Main table type: InnoDB
* Tables: 4
* Predicted rows per table: 2.000
* MySQL version: 5.1 (I think)
* Probable searches/day: 500
```

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: So 8k records in total with one search every few minutes? Then 64 MB should suffice.

Comment: 64MB? wow yeah so which operating system is going to run on 64MB? I want it...

Comment: @Namphibian Linux should be able to run that under light workload. These are virtual machines, so a lot of the hardware abstraction layer is not needed. The same goes for Windows, actually, but in that case 64 mb would still be too little.

Comment: @LexLythius agreed I use linux everyday. However if the workload is going to be so light why go with a heavy weight like mysql where something like BerkleyDB or another embedded database will probably be more suited.

Comment: @Namphibian Probably, because MySQL is the DB the author is already comfortable with.

Comment: @LexLythius he said in the question he is relatively new to MySQL databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of RAM dedicated to your database allows the database to keep part of the data in memory for fast access. Even if your database doesn't have very much memory, your queries would still run. 64MB should be enough for most queries.

The only time you need to worry about the RAM is when your query time is too long, only after you have done other optimizations such as indexing. Increasing the RAM if you see that many of your queries are going to the disk often.

For development work, 64MB is plenty. Even for small production loads, it's fine. If you don't mind your users waiting 1 sec for a page load, then 64MB is fine as well.

To be honest, 512MB is also fairly dinky. If you really need the performance after your site gets more traffic, get at least a couple of GB. RAM is fairly cheap anyway.

Comment: "RAM is fairly cheap anyway." Except in MediaTemple, IIRC. Anyway, I agree with you.